# Qcubed 2.3 Setting a future date if the current datefield is null

Tags: qcubed

Using QCubed 2.3  I am trying to set an ending date to way in the future if the current date field is null.  Essentially I want to load the Ending date (Edate) to this future date  when creating a new record.

Here is what I am trying to do with code from MetaControllGen.Class.php
/**
* Create and setup QDateTimePicker calEdate
* @param string $strControlId optional ControlId to use
* @return QDateTimePicker
*/
public function calEdate_Create($strControlId = null) {
$objhelp = Help::LoadByTag('pgdbendate');
$this->calEdate = new QJsCalendar($this->objParentObject, $strControlId);
$this->calEdate->Name = QApplication::Translate('Ending Date');
$this->calEdate->HtmlAfter = 'qmark.' border = 0> '.$objhelp->DocData.' ';
$this->calEdate->ToolTip = 'This data display will end on this date. Use for future for permanent data';

```
<--     if (!$this->objPagedb->Edate) $this->objPagedb->Edate = "Dec 31 2099" ; -->


        $this->calEdate->DateTime = $this->objPagedb->Edate;
        $this->calEdate->CalendarType = QJsCalendarType::Date;
        return $this->calEdate;
    }
```

Thanks for any help you can give.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out and answered my own question with the following code:

```
if (!$this->objPagedb->Edate) {
                $newdate = New QdateTime('now');
                $newdate->modify("+10 years");
                $this->objPagedb->Edate = $newdate ; 
            }
            $this->calEdate->DateTime = $this->objPagedb->Edate;
```

Hope this helps someone else still using Qcubed 2.3